# Push Notifications not delivered quickblox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, chat, quickblox

I am trying to send push notifications for offline users, but it is not sent to the device

Environment details:
ios chat app, I am using latest version from cocoapods

Expected behavior: It should show push notifications on the device

Actual behavior
I have uploaded the certificate,
[it is showing valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pt2M.png)

I have checked my device udid in subscription, [it is showing my device udid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szwz9.png)

The sent notification also [shows in queue on quickblox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZGSP.png) here is the log of sent push, it shows NULL in delivered and there is no error

```html
{
  "notification": {
    "id": 15460780,
    "badge": 45,
    "device_token": "0780db28ac60e37390e067f5b1d88688d804f594152827b1b28f86e670669530",
    "sound": "default",
    "alert": "Test User: Hello",
    "data": {
      "dialog_id": "5b3b4b9ba0eb474bbc0244eb",
      "user_id": 53886466,
      "message_id": "5b3b6a6b2d3084b447b7ad3d",
      "badge": 45,
      "headers": {
        "apns-topic": "com.company.app"
      },
      "__rpush_content_available__": true,
      "__rpush_mutable_content__": true
    },
    "expiry": 86400,
    "delivered": false,
    "delivered_at": null,
    "failed": false,
    "failed_at": null,
    "fail_after": "2018-07-03T13:22:05+00:00",
    "retries": 118,
    "error_code": null,
    "error_description": null,
    "deliver_after": "2018-07-03T12:31:57+00:00",
    "alert_is_json": null,
    "app_id": 23880,
    "collapse_key": null,
    "delay_while_idle": null,
    "registration_ids": null,
    "uri": null,
    "priority": null,
    "url_args": null,
    "category": null,
    "content_available": false,
    "mutable_content": false,
    "notification": null,
    "type": "Rpush::Client::Redis::Apns::Notification",
    "event_id": 24743581,
    "event_date": "2018-07-03T12:22:05+00:00"
  },
  "log": [
    {
      "device_token": "0780db28ac60e37390e067f5b1d88688d804f594152827b1b28f86e670669530",
      "delivered_at": null,
      "failed_at": null,
      "error_code": null,
      "error_description": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Also i have tried sending push through third party (pushtry.com) with same certificates and it is sending push but with quickblox, it is not showing any push notification

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is Quickblox server-side issue. Probably they haven't adjusted the server in appliance with recent changes in APNS. I asked their support, but they do not answer.

Comment: Same here, i have messaged their support 10 days ago and i have not get any reply from them :(

Answer (score 0):

json push notifciation for apple payload should be in below format

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Hello World",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "Person": {
        "Address": "this is a test address",
        "Name": "First Name",
        "Number": "023232323233"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, every thing is correct as per Apple requirement, even it is showing in the list of push queue at quickblox, but it is not delivering to any device that is strange